# Issue with URDF tutorial in ROS Groovy

Tags: urdf, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started on the tutorial [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) and ran the code for the example urdf -

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=01-myfirst.urdf
```

This gives me an error which goes like this -

> New config files have an .rviz extension and use YAML formatting. The format changed between Fuerte and Groovy. There is not (yet) an automated conversion program.

What should I do with this error? I didn't find any alternate way yet. Could anyone let me know about this? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68665/issue-with-urdf-tutorial-in-ros-groovy/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this file -

https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/blob/master/urdf_tutorial/urdf.rviz

and copied the file in the urdf_tutorial folder.

I then edited the **display.launch** file (using gedit) and changed "***urdf.vcg***" to "***urdf.rviz***" in that file.

It now works without any issues.

---

Originally posted by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) with karma: 237 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OReilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/6106/oreilly/) on 2013-08-22**:
Coming to the xacro portion of the tutorial, the same change must be made to the 'xacrodisplay.launch' file (urdf.vcg -- > urdf.rviz).